# Javascript getElementById cannot find div even if function is called at end of document

Tags: javascript, styles, display

I'm trying to make a toggle that would change an element's display to "none" if it's "block", and then if it's "block" to "none". Basically:

```
if (item.style.display == "none")
{
    item.style.display = "block";
}
else if (item.style.display == "block")
{
    item.style.display = "none";
}
```

I gave an ID to the element (id = "item"), but for some reason, my javascript function won't read the item.style.display

When I do alert(item.style.display), I get an empty alert. In the following code, I don't get any alerts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        #item
        {
                display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function showalert()
        {
                var item = document.getElementById('item');
                
                if (item.style.display == "none")
                {
                    alert("Not shown");
                }
                else if (item.style.display == "block")
                {
                    alert("shown");
                }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="item">
                Div item
        </div>
        <button onClick="showalert()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I've done this before, but I just can't seem to replicate it. I read a bunch of answers here, most of them were solved when the script was moved to the end of the document. However, I only defined the function in the script, and ran it near the end of the document, after the div element.

Can anyone show me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `item.style` does not see settings in a stylesheet. Instead check for an empty string or just for "block", or better, add and remove a class to update styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html DIV its wrong, you need to put the style display on the element to your IF works:

```
<div id="item" style="display:none;">
            Div item
</div>
<button onClick="showalert()">Click Me</button>

function showalert()
    {
            var item = document.getElementById('item');

            if (item.style.display == "none")
            {
                alert("Not shown");
            }
            else if (item.style.display == "block")
            {
                alert("shown");
            }
    }
```

So if the display of the Element DIV its none: the alert will be "Not shown"

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I tried that at first, but I had 2 elements in my original document, and only put the inline CSS on one of them, so it didn't work. Now I went back to check and put it on both elements and it's finally working.

Comment: @Panpaper: But don't do this. Inline styles are generally pretty undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Styles set by CSS stylesheets (and `<script>` tags) aren't accessible without [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) or setting the property directly in JS.

Here's an example setting the property directly in JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    #item {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="item">
    Div item
  </div>

  <script>
    var item = document.getElementById("item");
    item.style.display = "none";

    function toggle() {
      item.style.display = item.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And an example using `getComputedStyle`, which returns a live [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object which dynamically updates:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    #item {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="item">
    Div item
  </div>

  <script>
    const item = document.getElementById("item");
    const itemStyle = getComputedStyle(item, null);

    function toggle() {
      item.style.display = itemStyle.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternately, JS will recognize an inline style out of the box, but this isn't a particularly scalable solution.

It's also a good idea to `defer` the script, wrap it in an [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function, or simply move it to the bottom of the page. This avoids a situation where JS tries to access DOM elements that haven't yet loaded.

Comment: Amazing answer, I was looking to solve the problem but this taught me something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should toggle the display property between "none" and "" (empty string) so that the alternative is the default or inherited display value, e.g.

```
item.style.display = item.style.display == 'none'? '' : 'none';
```

Another approach is to add and remove a class as it's much more extensible and keeps logic separated, i.e. you're not mixing style and script.

E.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showalert, false);
}

function showalert(evt) {
  document.getElementById('item').classList.toggle('notShown');
}
```

```css
.notShown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div id="item" class="notShown">Div item</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```